# Android how to install apk stored in internal storage

Tags: java, android, apk, uri, android-internal-storage

I've successfully downloaded my apk file to internal storage.

However when running it I get an "No activity found to handle intent" error.

Here is my code to run the apk file.

```
// Old version
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
{
File apkFile = new File(this.pathToFile);
     if(apkFile.exists())
     {
          Uri apkURI = Uri.fromFile(apkFile);
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          intent.setData(apkURI);
          intent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
          intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, false);
          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: `my file path is actually /data/com.me.appName/files/update.apk`. That is an impossible path. Only on a rooted device it could have been created.

Comment: `successfully downloaded my apk file to internal storage.`. Well how did you manage to do that? Considering that impossible path.

Comment: You were talking about `this.pathToFile`?

Comment: `Android how to install apk stored in internal storage`. Wrong subject.

Comment: context.openFileOutput("app.apk", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); Is where it was saved. 

Then I stored pathToFile = context.getFilesDir().toString() + "/app.apk";

Comment: Then your path and pathToFile is /data/data/com.me.appName/files/update.apk

Comment: You're right. I must have messed up last night when typing this up.  However I've updated the question.  I added a check to make sure the file exists before launching the intent and it turns out that returns false.  I included my code to download the file in my post.  Can you tell me what's going wrong? Possibly wrong path?

Comment: Please add the check if that file exist to the code.

Comment: Your code looks ok. You are shure there is no excepion? How do you check? Also catch IOException.

Comment: `getFilesDir().toString() `. I would use getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() instead.

Comment: Gotcha I just changed that and updated the original post. 
When it launches the intent I get an error parsing package error and the app crashes.

Comment: I believe that there is a parsing error while the app gets installed by Android. But that your app would crash is strange. What is the Android version of device and app?

Comment: The app downloading the apk and the apk being downloaded target 4.0. 
The android version is 6.0.

Comment: I updated the post. Got download and constructing the URI just fine now. No longer target new os version that requires FileProvider. But even on old version I'm still having an issue with no activity found to handle intent.

Answer (score 0):

The apk cannot be installed using a content scheme.

You have to offer Android a file path to the apk file.

So do away with the FileProvider.

Further you should download to getExternalStorageDirectory() or getFilesDir() instead.

Comment: I do download to getFilesDir().
File apkFile = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/app.apk");

Comment: Yes i know. So dont do that was what i said.

Comment: Is there any reason to choose ExternalStorage over getFilesDir()? My reason for choosing getFilesDir is because every device has it where not every device has external storage media.

Comment: Every device has external storage. And a lot of devices have also removeble storage if a micro SD card can be inserted. Do not use getFilesDir() as it s private internal storage for your app only. So other apps have no acces. Im afraid that your apk cannot be installed from internal storage. Well if Android installs the apk then it should have acces. But please try both. Why not?

Comment: The apk is not the app that tries to instal it? Or is it?

Comment: I have app1 which is where all this code is.  And it is trying to install app2 (The apk downloaded). I am going to change my code to use external storage now and see what happens.

Comment: Changed it to File apkFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/app-release.apk");
But I'm still getting the no activity found error.

Comment: You removed the download code. But if you stil use openFileOutput() you are still saving to getFilesDir(). Use FileOutputStream instead with a full parh. Not only a file name as you do now.

Comment: Or did you change it? You still have the exists check before the intent,? Better shiw full code.

Comment: I scratched my approach entirely and used https://stackoverflow.com/a/4969421/7129932

I did change it from openFileOutput but still had no luck with installation for whatever reason.  I appreciate your time spent trying to help me, you're a good person.